# Убрать Not Found

Tags: php

Хочу сделать на сайте систему рефералов. Чтобы реф. ссылки были вида `my_site.ru/login` где `login` - логин пользователя, который пригласил пользователя.
Из адресной строки  я получу его логин того кто пригласил пользователя, а с помощью логина я получу *id* и всю нужную информацию.
Но проблема вот в чем, если перейти на `my_site.ru/login` - выдает Not Found.
Как можно решить данную проблему не мешая мне реализовать задуманную реф систему?

Comment: Ну так у вас сейчас нет такой системы, потому и говорит, что ничего не найдено. Как сделаете такую систему, то будет все нормально работать (если, конечно, сделаете и сделаете нормально)

Comment: И почему в начале вы пишите про `site.ru/login`, а в конце уже про `my_site.ru/login`? Это разные сайты что ли? Так чему тогда удивляться?

Comment: @BOPOH так мне сначала нужно чтоб не отвечало Not Found...

Comment: @BOPOH это не разные сайты, просто для примера написал

Comment: Вы понимаете, что для того, чтобы ваш сайт не писал `not found` вы должны что-то сделать на нем? Например, тех же рефералов (хотя бы заготовку для них). Вы не привели никакого кода, не указали какую CMS используете (или что там у вас), и что вы хотите от нас получить? Что вам надо, я сказал - сделать рефералов, тогда (если сделаете нормально) - у вас не будет такой ошибки

Comment: @BOPOH мне нужно чтобы при переходе на `my_site.ru/login` открывалась страница регистрации. Но `login` будет разный. может просто в ".штакет" добавить правило ErrorDocument 404 /registration ?

Comment: Настраиваете ваш сайт так, чтобы он вместо 404 ошибки кидал на вашу страницу регистрации. Как - не знаю, вы не указали CMS, не указали с чем работаете, а тыкать в небо пальцем вещь неблагодарная, можно случайно проткнуть его

Comment: CMS нет, я пишу с нуля.

Comment: @Денис , судя по вашим вопросам пишите не вы, а те кто отвечают на ваши вопросы.

Comment: @Visman а вы сразу встали и пошли?\

Comment: @Денис , нет, но я смотрел как у других реализовано, а не просил написать для меня код. Благо, открытого кода в интернете уйма.

Comment: @Visman тогда в чем смысл этого ресурса?

Comment: @Денис, этот ресурс ставит целью дать возможность найти ответы на действительно сложные и неочевидные вопросы. Хотя, к моему глубокому сожалению, большинство вопросов сводится либо к "_напишите код за меня_" либо к "_где в моем коде допущена опечатка_".

Comment: @DmitriySimushev +1. Еще встречаются варианты: *Есть идея написать распределенную систему промышленного уровня для предприятий, подскажите как на C++ добавить элемент в массив?* :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Apache, в корне, в файле `.htaccess` необходимо прописать

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/{0,1}$ getuserdata.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

В файле `getuserdata.php` работаете с переменной `$_GET['user']`, примерно так:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['user'])."'
```

Comment: благодарю ,то что нужно!

Comment: Очень вредный запрос sql представлен. Хотя для хакеров одно раздолье.

Comment: @Visman может использовать `mysql_escape_string` ?

Comment: @Visman в чем проблема запроса? Аргументируйте.

Comment: Для экранирования строк в sql запросах есть свои функции. addslashes к ним не относится.

Comment: @Денис , mysql устарел. Минимально возможно использование mysqli. И для него есть функция экранирования mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: @Visman, для `mysql` тоже есть функция `mysql_real_escape_string`. Хотя в остальном вы правы -- нельзя писать новый код на базе расширения `mysql`.